# Prove the inequality $r+1 \leq \exp r^\varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon>0$ for sufficiently large values of $r$

Tags: inequality

As the title suggests, I am trying to prove
$$ r+1 \leq \exp (r^\varepsilon), \hspace{4mm} \varepsilon > 0 $$
when $r$ is sufficiently large.

Any help would be great!

Comment: @wythagoras I deleted my comment accordingly. But the OP could instead compare $\log (r+1)$ and $r^{\epsilon}$.

Comment: @Martigan Right, I think that works using l'Hopital. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the following.

Choose a number $n>1/\varepsilon$. Then

$$\exp (r^\varepsilon)>\frac {r^{n\varepsilon}}{n!}> r+1,$$

when $r$ is sufficiently large.